# Autofit row height in RTF Template

Tags: oraclereports, bi-publisher, oracle-apps, oracleapplications

I am using MS Word 2007 on a Windows 7 system and created a RTF Template for XML Publisher Report.
But the output of report (in Excel) has the "row height collaps" issue. Everytime, user has to do manully "Autofit row height".
How could I set "Autofit row height" form RTF-Template itself so that output Excel File shouldn't have this "row height" issue.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Word allows you to specify the table row height as Auto, Exactly, or At-least. You might like to select the table-formatting option from the context menu while the cursor is on the table row.  Then select the "Row' tab. Now ensure that the 'Specify Height' box is unchecked.  This makes the row as auto-fit which expands as needed.